# Simple modules in the decomposition of modular group algebra KG

Tags: representation-theory, semi-simple-rings

Suppose F is a field such that $char(F) = p \ \nmid \ |G|.$ Then we know that in this  case (i.e. semisimple), there is a bijection between the irreducible representations of G and the simple components appearing in the wedderbern artin decomposition of FG. Does something similar happen in modular case?
I just know that if $char(K) = p \ | \ |G,|$ then  corresponding to each simple module S of $KG,$ there is an indecomposable projective module P such that $\displaystyle \frac{P}{rad(P)} \cong S.$ But how does that S appear in the decomposition of $KG?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something a bit similar happens in characteristic $p$, but much more complicated. One may still write $KG$ as a direct sum of indecomposable $2$-sided ideal summands, but they are no longer in bijection with simple modules. These are called the ($p$-)blocks. Each block $B$ is a subalgebra, and when considered as a $KG$-module, $B$ breaks up as a direct sum of projective indecomposable modules $P_1,\dots,P_r$, with simple tops $S_1,\dots,S_r$. If $\dim(S_i)=a$ then $P_i$ is isomorphic to exactly $a$ of the $P_j$, as in the decomposition of $FG$, but each simple module $S$ appears in *exactly one* block. Occasionally a block $B$ restricts to just $S^{\oplus \dim (S)}$, i.e., it looks exactly as in the characteristic $0$ case. In this case, the block has *defect zero*, and is isomorphic to a matrix algebra. But in general there are lots of blocks that are not matrix algebras, for example the one with a trivial quotient. This block is called the *principal block*, and is a matrix algebra if and only if $p\nmid |G|$.

Comment: This answer is perfect as is, I would just add the easy example of $A=\mathbb{F}_2 S_2$. Clearly $A=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2-1)=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/((x-1)^2) = \mathbb{F}_2[y]/(y^2)$ where $y=x-1$. Then $A$ has the unique submodule $(y)$, and $A/(y)$ is the simple module $\mathbb{F}_2$, which is of course trivial.

Comment: Thanks! @AlvaroMartinez . Since S2 is cyclic, it was easy to see. What can we say if the group is, say, S_5?

Comment: That is a good question and the beginning of modular representation theory. This will vary for p=2,3,5, but there will always be nontrivial blocks as in David’s answer. There is a beautiful theory behind this. The first step is this: there are as many blocks as simples, and as many simples as conjugacy classes of order coprime to p. I recommend Webb’s representation theory book (I think S_5 is worked out there), Alperin’s Local representation theory, or even Serre’s book.

Comment: Each block contains a simple module, but there are in general far fewer blocks than there are simple modules.